# getting a name of module or script which logs messages using log4perl

Tags: perl, log4perl

If a particular module is logging using log4perl then is there any way to get the name of that module using log4perl internally.  or message is logged from srcipt(.pl) can we get the name of script also using log4perl only apart from using caller or any function which doesnt use log4perl function explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

For classes or packages, you can do that. It's [documented with Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl#Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout). In your log pattern, use one of the following.

> ```
> %C Fully qualified package (or class) name of the caller
> ```

And for the name of a script:

> ```
> %F File where the logging event occurred
> ```

These ones are also useful:

> ```
> %l Fully qualified name of the calling method followed by the
>    callers source the file name and line number between 
>    parentheses.
> %L Line number within the file where the log statement was issued
> ```

The documentation of [Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout) itself has even more details.

[Here's an example](https://metacpan.org/pod/Log::Log4perl#Initialize-via-a-configuration-file) of how to use this with a config file.

> ```
> log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.layout=PatternLayout
> log4perl.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%r] %F %L %c - %m%n
> ```

Comment: @Mr_perl I don't know. Please include the things you already know in your question next time. It took me a few minutes to find this in the documentation, and I would not have needed to do that had you included your own research.

Comment: @Mr_perl: Then I don't understand your requirement. It sounds like you want to get the name of the calling module from within that module, but it already knows its own name. Please give a proper example of the code you want to write.

Comment: @Mr_perl please include more information into your question. You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43467923/edit).